# json array parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json array printed out from php file. 
And then tried to get elements by parsing it. But I am confused where is wrong.

```
    <?php

    $json = array("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5".......);
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>

    <script>
    $.ajax({
    /*other codes*/

    success : function(data){

            var json = parseJSON(data);
            for(var i = 0 ; i < json.length; i++){
               alert(json[i]);
            }

            }
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: So no errors in the browser's console? What is the `parseJSON()` function that you are calling? Did you mean `$.parseJSON()`, or `JSON.parse()`?  Note that if you specify `dataType: 'json'` in your Ajax call then jQuery will parse the JSON for you *before* calling your success function, in which case `data` will be the object already and trying to parse it again wouldn't work.

Comment: ReferenceError: parseJSON is not defined

Comment: `But I am confused where is wrong.` I am confused what you're asking

Comment: my json array is without key. my question is how to parse that array.

Comment: try, `var json = JSON.parse(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        ...
```

The response (data) is in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is a `JSON String` then you can use `JSON.parse()` method to convert it into JSON Object and then we can parse it using [**Array map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method or [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
var result = json.map(function(item) {
    return item;
});
```